# Is it possible to determine if an event was triggered programmatically?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is it possible to determine if an event such as `input`, `blur`, `change` etc. was fired due to a user interaction or if it was fired programmatically using `inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))` etc.?

The problem I am facing is that a third-party UI library registered an event handler that listens for `blur` and changes the appearance of an input element if it's empty. I have an own `blur` handler that blanks the input if certain criteria is met. Since my event handler is executed after the library's, the library doesn't notice that the input is now empty and re-throwing the blur event would cause an endless loop.

Or is it safe to add custom properties to events, something like...

```js
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('blur', event => {
  if (event.myOwnCustomProperty !== true) {
    event.target.value = ''
    const customEvent = new Event('blur')
    customEvent.myOwnCustomProperty = true
    event.target.dispatchEvent(customEvent)
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="input">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) property of the event to check whether it was triggered by user interaction or not:

> The `isTrusted` read-only property of the `Event` interface is a `Boolean` that is `true` when the event was generated by a user action, and `false` when the event was created or modified by a script or dispatched via `EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`.

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('blur', event => {
  if (event.isTrusted) {
    ...
  }
})
```

Note that the user can still fire events from the debugger, either manually or programatically, and in this case you will never know where the event originated from.